# Automatically post new pictures from folder to Instagram using API

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

I'm working on a project for a youth event.  They are planning to set up a photo booth and they want to post to Instagram.  As with many things I have pretty much no budget.  I have a photo booth program that saves files to a directory.  I'd trying to set up a Python program to monitor that folder and post new files to Instagram automatically.  Monitoring the folder isn't the problem.  I'm having difficulty getting the API to post.  I'm using the [Unofficial API](https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python) from LevPasha. 
 Here is my code below along with the output. It looks like it works but, I don't see any posts.  Most of the code was borrowed from another post.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI

api = InstagramAPI(userName, password)

if (api.login()):

    api.getSelfUserFeed()  # get self user feed

    #print(api.LastJson)  # print last response JSON

    print("Login succes!")

    photoPath = 'portrait.jpg'

    caption = "Company outing last fall"

    InstagramAPI.uploadPhoto(api,"portrait.jpg", "Test Post")

    print("Photo posted.")

else:

   print("Can't login!")

print(api.login())
```

**Output**

Fail to import moviepy. Need only for Video upload.
Request return 405 error!
{'message': '', 'status': 'fail'}
Request return 404 error!
Login success!

Login succes!
Photo posted.
None

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: side question dave, but how did you get past getting a challenge required error when using api.login()?